# "The localhost page isn’t working" or out of memory issues with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add in a search page using checkboxes to select what the user wants to find.  However I keep geting The localhost page isn’t working error 500 or something about not being enough memory

> Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes

I changed the php.ini to have 512M and I still got this error, before it said 134...bytes. I've reboot and reset everything.

Here is my code:
The searchType page:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;


class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('botanicalname', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Botanical Name:'))
            ->add('commonname', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Common Name:'))
            ->add('wetsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Wet Soil:'))
            ->add('moistsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Moist Soil:'))
            ->add('peatysoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Peaty Soil:'))
            ->add('welldrainedsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Well-drained Soil:'))
            ->add('drought', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Drought:'))
            ->add('claysoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Clay Soil:'))
            ->add('sandysoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Sandy Soil:'))
            ->add('loamsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Loam Soil:'))
            ->add('infertilesoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Infertile Soil:'))
            ->add('richsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Rich Soil:'))
            ->add('compactedsoil', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Compacted Soil:'))
            ->add('cityconditions', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates City Conditions:'))
            ->add('pollution', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Pollution:'))
            ->add('salt', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Salt Conditions:'))
            ->add('windy', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Windy Conditions:'))
            ->add('shade', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Shade:'))
            ->add('partshade', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Part Shade:'))
            ->add('fullsun', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Prefers Full Sun:'))
            ->add('pestproblem', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Pest Problem:'))
            ->add('phpreference', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Pest Problem:'))
            ->add('borderlinehardy', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'BorderLine Hardy'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'));





    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Shrubs'
        ));
    }

    /** * {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getBlockPrefix(){
        return 'appbundle_shrubs';}
}
```

The controller:

```
 /**
     * Creates a new Shrubs entity.
     *
     * @Route("/search", name="shrubs_search")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        return $this->render('shrubs/search.html.twig', array(

            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

And my search page just have the twig form thing. Any ideas?

Comment: In php.ini are you sure it is set at 512M? maybe it wants max size in bytes and the M is ignored?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I just double checked to be sure.

Comment: `SearchType::class` used in the builder is the same class (as `class SearchType extends AbstractType`). I would guess thats the issue here... some kind of circular reference. According to your description I would expect something like `$builder->add('...', SearchCheckboxType::class`... and therefore you need another class for the `SearchCheckboxType` or just use the built-in `CheckboxType`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - sorry. If I change SearchType::class to SearchCheckboxType::class it says undefined class?

Comment: Thats what I mean by: "and therefore you need another class for the SearchCheckboxType or just use the built-in CheckboxType"

Comment: Let me explain your issue: A form type defines a form field or a collection of such. You define a `SearchType` containing multiple `SearchType`... or in other words, containing itself, which leads to a circular reference issue or infinate loop which then f**** up your memory.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you just want to build a form containing checkboxes so just try `$builder->add('...', CheckboxType::class, ...` and don't forget the use statement for `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType`.

Comment: I used the checkBoxType and that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular reference issue. You define a form type `SearchTyp` which contains itself: `$builder->add('...', SearchType::class, ...)`. This is not possible. If I understand you correctly, at the moment, you just want a form containing checkboxes. You can use the built-in `CheckboxTyp` from symfony as you already do with `TextType`, `SubmitType` and so on (at least you have use statements for them):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType; # don't forget...


class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('botanicalname', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Botanical Name:'))
            ->add('commonname', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Common Name:'))
            ->add('wetsoil', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Tolerates Wet Soil:'))
            // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```